# React ref returns a 'Connect' object instead of DOM

Tags: reactjs, dom, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create dynamics refs for custom components created through the map function.

```html
class PostsList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    console.log(this.refs);
  }

  render() {
    let posts = this.props.posts || [];
    return (
        <div ref="test">
          {posts.map((post) => {
            return <Post post={post} key={post.id} ref={post.id}></Post>
          })}
        </div>
    );
  }

}

export default PostsList
```

the `console.log` returns the correct DOM node for `refs.test` but for the ones in the loop, it's returning a `Connect` Object.
[image: Screenshot]

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems like `Post` is a connected component, while you actually want the wrapped one.

**`react-redux ≥ 6.0.0`**

Connect with `forwardRef: true`

```
connect(null, null, null, { forwardRef: true })(Post);
```

then add a ref normally:

```
ref={ref => this.<id> = ref}
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/50883450079356e70828139e531303a962b85458/docs/api/connect.md#forwardref-boolean):

> If `{forwardRef : true}` has been passed to `connect`, adding a ref to the
>   connected wrapper component will actually return the instance of the
>   wrapped component.

---

**`react-redux < 6`**

Connect with `withRef: true`

```
connect(null, null, null, { withRef: true })(Post);
```

then use `getWrappedInstance()` to get the underlying connected component:

```
this.refs[<id>].getWrappedInstance()
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md):

> [withRef] (Boolean): If true, stores a ref to the wrapped component instance and makes it available via `getWrappedInstance()` method. Default value: `false`

Comment: In my `Post.jsx`, I added `export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {withRefs: true})(Post);` And when I try to call `getWrappedInstance()` in my PostList.jsx, it emits the error `Error: To access the wrapped instance, you need to specify { withRef: true } in the options argument of the connect() call.`

edit: sorry, i see my error now, should be withRef, not withRefs

Comment: Has been changed from `withRef` to `forwardRef`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to do this would be to use some other prop name (other than `ref`). For example:

```
<Post
  ...
  innerRef={(node) => { this.myRef = node; }}
/>
```

This also works if you're using a library like `styled-components` or `emotion`