# How to get reference to a react componenet in its container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a container liked to a component.
When `onRegionsChange` runs, I need to call a function of `Map`. How to achieve it?

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Map from './Map'
import { setRegion } from './mapActions'

const map = state => {
  return state.mapReducer.map.data
}

const getRegions = state => {
  return state.mapReducer.map.data.regions
}

const getTypes = state => {
  return state.mapReducer.map.data.types
}

const geo = state => {
  return state.mapReducer.map.app.geo
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    geo: geo(state),
    map: map(state),
    regions: getRegions(state),
    types: getTypes(state)
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onRegionsChange: (region) => {
      console.log('onRegionsChange')
      dispatch(setRegion(region))
    },
    onTypesChange: (navigation) => {
      console.log('onTypesChange')
    }
  }
}

const MapContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Map)

export default MapContainer
```

Notes: I cannot get reference to getWrappedInstance

Comment: should `MapContainer` wrap around `Map`? why not pass a reference of a handler to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React ref returns a 'Connect' object instead of DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554365/react-ref-returns-a-connect-object-instead-of-dom)

Comment: MapContainer  wrap around map, could you please post an example?

Comment: It is not really a duplicate, as I am not able to get getWrappedInstance on the wrapper, it tells undefined

Comment: @Radex Are you using the `{ withRef: true }` option?

Comment: yes but did not work

Comment: @Radex Please post your updated code.