# Access exposed methods via ref

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple component that exposes a method called `doIt`, however this component is wrapped in a redux `connect` so I am not able to access it. Here is my simple component:

```
class LoginSwitchDumb extends Component {
    render() { ... }
    doIt = (value: boolean) => alert('hi')
}

const LoginSwitch = connect(...)(LoginSwitchDumb)

export LoginSwitch
```

I render this element in my parent like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <LoginSwitch id={id} kind={kind} ref={this.refSwitch} />
        </View>
    )
}

refSwitch = el => {
    console.log('reffing switch:', Object.keys(el));
}
```

However we see on the console log in `refSwitch`, it is not giving me access to `doIt`. If I don't wrap it in `connect` I can access it, this is what is logged when not wrapped with `connect`:

> Array [ "props", "context", "refs", "updater", "doIt", "_reactInternalInstance", "state" ]

We see the `doIt` here, but when I wrap it with `connect`, it is not there, we see this instead:

> Array [ "props", "context", "refs", "updater", "version", "state", "renderCount", "store", "propsMode", "setWrappedInstance", "selector", "subscription", "notifyNestedSubs", "_reactInternalInstance" ]

Is there anyway to tap this to get to `doIt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React ref returns a 'Connect' object instead of DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554365/react-ref-returns-a-connect-object-instead-of-dom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`getWrappedInstance`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#getwrappedinstance-reactcomponent) on the wrapped component in order to get the underlying component instance. In order to do that, you also need to pass `{ withRef: true }` in the options to [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

```
const LoginSwitch = connect(..., ..., ..., { withRef: true })(LoginSwitchDumb)
```

and in the parent:

```
refSwitch = el => {
  console.log('reffing switch:', Object.keys(el.getWrappedInstance()));
}
```

Comment: Oooo! Thanks very much Ross!!

Comment: Hi there sir, quick follow on this q please. Is it better practice to store on ref like this `refSwitch = el => this.switch = el` then wheneever I need to use it, I should do `this.el.getWrappedInstance().BLAH` or should I save the instance on ref so like this: `refSwitch = el => this.switch = el.getWrappedInstance()`?

Comment: Also I notice that there is also `el.wrappedInstance`. But this is not documented at https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments-1 is this because its a perf issue or something so we should prefer `getWrappedInstance`?

Comment: @Noitidart I would guess `el.wrappedInstance` is a reference that's returned by calling `getWrappedInstance()`. If `wrappedInstance` isn't documented, I suggest sticking to the documented `getWrappedInstance`.

Comment: Thanks @Ross - do you think when ref is triggered I should hold on to `el.getWrappedInstance()` or should I just hold on to `el` and when I need to use i should do `el.getWrappedInstance().blah()`?